# Component only rerenders if ternary expression is directly inside render() method

Tags: react-redux

I'm building an app with React, Redux and TypeScript.

In the top navbar I have a "Log in" link which when clicked dispatches an action. For now, all this action does is set a boolean called `auth` to true.

I have a lot of connected components which listen to that `auth` property of the redux store and decide which sub-components to render, based on ternary expressions that evaluate `this.props.auth`.

I was surprised to see that when I clicked "Log in" some components would rerender as expected while others would have their state successfully changed but would only alter their display if I refreshed the page or routed away and came back. After some hours of hair-pulling I believe I finally isolated the difference between the two kinds of components described above: if the ternary expression that evaluates `this.props.auth` is directly inside the `render()` method, the component behaves as expected, however, if the ternary expression is inside a `.map()` function which is then called by the `render()` method, then this weird behavior happens where I have to refresh in order for the correct rendering to match the prop values. What's going on? Does `this` lose it's value, is this a sync/async problem?

```
class LatestArticles extends Component<LatestArticlesProps> {

public latestArticlesList: JSX.Element[] = Articles.map((a: IArticle) => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment key={a.id}>
            // some TSX

                        {this.props.auth === true ? <UserImgOverlay /> : <UnlockButton />}

            // some more TSX
        </React.Fragment>
    )
});

public render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            // some TSX

                    {this.latestArticles}

            // some more TSX
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Do let me know if you need any more context but I would like to ask for help understanding what's going on. Why does the prop change only trigger a rerender if the ternary expression is directly inside the `render()` method and is there any way to go around this while still mapping the data? Thank you for your attention.

**EDIT**

Here's my mapStateToProps:

```
// Components/Navbar/index.tsx

const mapStateToProps = ({ articles, auth }: IApplicationState) => {
    return {
        articlesPerPage: articles.articlesPerPage,
        articlesPerPageStep: articles.articlesPerPageStep,
        auth: auth.auth
    }
}
```

I actually have another example of this kind of behavior happening with an onClick method:

```
class LatestArticles extends Component<LatestArticlesProps> {

    public latestArticlesList: JSX.Element[] = Articles.map((a: IArticle) => {
        return (
            <React.Fragment key={a.id}>
                // some TSX

                            <StarsRating rating={3} onClick={this.handleRatingClick} />

                // some more TSX
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    });

    constructor(props: LatestArticlesProps & IOwnProps) {
        super(props)

        this.handleRatingClick = this.handleRatingClick.bind(this);
    }

    public render(): JSX.Element {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                // some TSX

                        {this.latestArticles}

                // some more TSX
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }

    public handleRatingClick = () => {
        alert('Clicked!')
    }
}
```

^ When I click on the star nothing happens, but if I extract `<StarsRating rating={3} onClick={this.handleRatingClick} />` from the .map function and put it directly inside the render() method, I get the alert saying 'Clicked!'... I suspect `this` is losing its value but I'm not sure how to test that.

Comment: I don't think it's related to the map. How do you pass `auth` to this component? Could you please add `mapStateToProps`?

Comment: Added the mapStateToProps and also another example of what appears to be a symptom of the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with the `latestArticlesList` variable. It is initialized too early. It should be a function:

```
public latestArticlesList: JSX.Element[] = () => Articles.map((a: IArticle) => {
```

I assume `Articles` should be `this.props.articlesPerPage`.

And finally when you use it, call it:

```
<React.Fragment>
  // some TSX

  {this.latestArticles()}

  // some more TSX
</React.Fragment>
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked perfectly thank you so much. I've been typing my mapped variables as `variableName: JSX.Element[]` and initializing them before the constructor, when instead they should be functions `variableName = (): JSX.Element[]`. Problem solved, thank you again.

`this.props.articlesPerPage` is actually the number of articles to display.